# How do I rescue an exception from inside an Enumerator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, enumerator, rescue

I'm writing an application in Rails and I want to get a huge amount of information from an API – which I'm streaming through an Enumerator object as a CSV export. I want to **rescue** an error that is called within the Enumerator.

#### CONTROLLER: Enumerator

```
def csv_lines( url )
    Enumerator.new do |y|
        per_page = 200

        # Parse parameters and get shelf information
        _params = BrowseScraper.get_params(url)
        shelf = BrowseScraper.get_preso( _params, 0 )
            total_items = shelf['response']['total_results']['all'].to_i
            total_pages = ( total_items / per_page.to_f ).ceil
            shelf_info  = BrowseScraper.crawl_ids( shelf['response']['query']['category'] )

        y << BrowseScraper.csv_header(url, shelf_info, total_items, ["Tool ID", "Name", "Price", "URL"])

        total_pages.times { |i| y << BrowseScraper.csv_body( _params, per_page, i+1) }
    end
end
```

The following functions are raising errors, but I can't catch them outside of the Enumerator:

#### MODEL: methods

```
def self.get_params
  response = open(url)
  raise if response.code != 200
end
```

#### CONTROLLER: Display

```
def export
    url = params[:url]
    raise StandardError, "Please enter a Browse URL below" if !url || url.empty?

    respond_to do |format|
        format.csv do
            render_csv(url)
        end
        format.html { render_csv(url) }
    end
rescue => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to scraper_path
end

private
    def render_csv( url )
        set_file_headers
        set_streaming_headers

        response.status = 200

        # Rails should iterate this enumerator
        self.response_body = csv_lines(url)
    end

    def set_file_headers( name = "browse_export" )
        headers["Content-Type"] ||= 'text/csv'
        headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"#{name}.csv\""
        headers["Content-Transfer-Encoding"] = "binary"
        headers["Last-Modified"] = Time.now.ctime.to_s
    end

    def set_streaming_headers
        #nginx doc: Setting this to "no" will allow unbuffered responses suitable for Comet and HTTP streaming applications
        headers['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no'
        headers["Cache-Control"] ||= "no-cache"
        headers.delete("Content-Length")
    end
```

Rescuing the error raised in `export` works. Rescuing an error within the Enumerator works (example:

```
Enumerator do |y|
  begin
    y << BrowseScraper.get_params(_params)
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.error "Failed to get parameters: #{e.message}"
  end
end
```

How can I rescue an exception outside of the Enumerator so I can properly redirect the user with a flash message? How do I pass the exception from within the Enumerator object? What is it about the Enumerator that *isn't letting me* rescue it with:

```
def method
    Enumerator do |y|
        y << BrowseScraper.get_params(_params)
    end
rescue => e
    Rails.logger.error "Error in Enumerator is #{e.message}"
end
```

Comment: There is nothing special about `Enumerator` class and you can rescue uncatched exceptions in a wrapping begin/rescue block. In your `method` method you are rescuing a `StandardError` - the default when exception class omitted. Are you sure your code raises this kind of exception or its sublass ?

Comment: Hey @DavidUnric, thanks for the reply. I made sure to throw only `StandardError`s or write classes that are based on `StandardError`s. I can even see that I'm rescuing the right error within the `Enumerator`. But I can't rescue it outside of it. Is this an issue of instance, where I need to rescue it on the first instance of the `Enumerator`?

Comment: Unless exception rescued inside Enumerator it propagates to outer scope. Following code when run `def method; (1..10).each {|i| raise StandardError if i > 5; p i}; rescue; p 'gotcha'; end` would print numbers 1 to 5, then string 'gotcha' as exception is rescued.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific and put in an example what instance of `Enumerator` are you actually using.

Comment: It seems like the instance is called by [self.response_body](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/756baf296b3cb3f7bc40d5843e259276695071ab/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L183), which then iterates over the enumerator.    I guess the way I phrased the question is no longer valid. It seems like you can rescue from `Enumerators`, but since the iteration is done by `response_body`, I don't have a way to access the part where I need to rescue it... So I guess I need to do my own `response_body` that overrides it or something of that sort.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I'm not able to catch the exception generated inside the Enumerator, for example: self.response_body = Enumerator.new { |y| raise 'Error' } . I tried 'rescue' inside Enumerator and also in the action, neither worked. I'm using jruby and torquebox. I'm getting an ugly page from torquebox/jbos and I'd like to customize the error page using rails. Anyone find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured out what's going on here. When you write code in an Enumerator, the block isn't actually executed within the Enumerator. Therefore, if I add a `rescue` within the Enumerator, it doesn't matter.

This is because the `|y|` in Enumerator is actually a yielder object which does the yielding (more on that in the [Enumerator documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-new) or the [Enumerator::Yielder documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Enumerator/Yielder%3ayield).

You have to rescue things beforehand.